# Can I sync the scrollbars of two different windows?

Tags: firefox, windows

## Problem

In Windows, I have two Mozilla Firefox windows side by side on a screen.  Right now I am scrolling through two different output logs to see the difference in the logs.

## Question

Is there a way to scroll through both these windows at the same time without manually clicking between windows each time?

Comment: If you're looking at logs, try a different approach.  There are tools for comparing files side by side, often used by programmers.  I don't know what's available for Windows, but in Linux, for example, there's kdiff3.  It displays the contents side-by-side, aligning what's the same, and you scroll through both together.  There must be comparable software for Windows.  Worst case, boot up a live Linux session, run kdiff3 there, and compare the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. You can only scroll in an active window. On some programs and browser, this active area can be elevated under the mouse cursor instead of an active window, but technically there haven't been invented such solution which would be able to simultaneously and in sync move scroll bar on two windows.